# How to modify the subject line in Nagios email alerts

Tags: nagios

I have Nagios alerts setup and working properly.

I need to modify the subject line of all alert emails - to include a constant string.

How can I modify the subject line in Nagios email alerts?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects
2. vi commands.cfg

There you'll find notify-host-by-email and notify-service-by-email. 
Here is the example of notify-host-by-email:

```
define command{  
       command_name    notify-host-by-email  
       command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n$NOTIFICATIONCOMMENT$" | /usr/sbin/sendmail sudo -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```

4. Add YOUR_SUBJECT

define command{

```
command_name    notify-host-by-email  
command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "**Subject: YOUR_SUBJECT\n******* Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState:..."
```

Comment: The subject is the stuff after the `-s` parameter in the original command. Moving it into the message body is a bad idea...

Answer (score 1):

If you have gone through a basic setup, there will be a command within "commands.cfg" that is used to send emails called "notify-host-by-email" and "notify-service-by-email".

There will be a long string under the "command_name" directive, you can edit that string to change the details that are submitted to en email.